# PHP ADODB with MySQL: ADODB object not working within functions

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

Given a file called index.php which contains:

```
$db = NewADOConnection($db_dsn);
if (!$db) die("Connection failed");   

$arrpage = $db->GetArray("SELECT * FROM somewhere");

include("functions.inc.php");

details("SELECT * FROM somewherelse");
```

The $arrpage contains the expect information

Then in the functions.inc.php file:

```
function details($query) {
  global $db; //should check to make sure it exists

  $options_array = $db->GetArray($query);
```

The $options_array is empty even though it should contain data.
var_dump($db) shows the DB object is all there. var_dump($options_array) is blank.

- PHP 5.3.4
- MySQL 14.14
- ADODB 5.14

Comment: Have details() var_dump($db), if that fails then start proving that the correct include file being found.

Comment: Done that. I've debugged this thing to the nines. I'm going to start looking at the PHP and MySQL configs because it works on my mates machine who's running PHP 5.3.5

Comment: So did the sql make it to your mysql engine? Check the end of the mysql log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of troubleshooting, all I needed to do was get up, have a pint of good beer and come back to it another time.

The short of it is: the system uses caching and upon close inspection of my error logs I noticed that the the cache files weren't being written to the cache folder because of folder permission issues.

I therefore fixed the folder permissions and now that the cache files can be saved, the DB query has something to refer to.

Thanks for the help anyways, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$options_array = $db->GetAll($query);
```

Comment: can you post more from your details() function please